# How do I replicate the Excel Percentage format in ClosedXML

Tags: excel, format, percentage, closedxml

I have a column of fractional numbers between 0 and 1.  In Excel, if I use the Format Cells option and select Percentage the displayed values are between 0% and 100% as expected.

Is there any way in Closed XML to set this Percentage format such that it both multiplies by 100 and appends the % symbol before display?  All the suggestions I have found use the NumberFormat that simply appends a % to the number between 0 and 1.  I don't really want to multiply the value by 100 before I add it to the cell as it will affect other computations.

```
ws.Column(iC+1).Style.NumberFormat.Format = "0.000\%";
```

Answer (score 0):

Just don't escape the `%` character:

```
ws.Column(iC+1).Style.NumberFormat.Format = "0.000%";
```